# Display this year ( php ) does not validate

Tags: php, validation

Any idea why this does not validate ( under w3c )

```
<?=date('Y')?>
```

Doc type

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
```

Yellow Triangle warning:
Line 78, Column 40: processing instruction does not start with name

Red cross warning:
Line 78, Column 29: xmlParsePI : no target name

LIne of code it is in is:

```
<p>&copy; Copyright 2011 - <?=date('Y') ?> </p>
```

Comment: What do you have as a result? Are you sure that your short open tags are enabled in php config? It looks like `<?=date('Y') ?>` goes directly to the output unchanged.

Comment: thats a good point, I dont know. What would be a fail safe method for this. We get no browes errors, renders 100% , but w3c wont validate it

Comment: Look at the generated content. Or enable short open tags in php.ini. Or rewrite it as `<?php echo date('Y'); ?>`

Comment: would <?php echo date("Y") ?> be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have short tags turned on in PHP?

Replace your

```
<?=date('Y')?>
```

with this:

```
<?php echo date('Y'); ?>
```

..and see what happens?

Comment: Hadnt crossed my mind. Obviously not, because now she validates lol. Cheers buddy